# ddwrt iptables issue - I want to forward all traffic to an external proxy

Tags: proxy, external, tunnel

I have an external squid 3 proxy server in Florida. I am in Michigan. I want to tunnel all traffic through my router to the proxy server in Florida. I am sure I need to do this with iptables but I am not getting it. I have read the ddwrt transparent proxy wiki and the problem is that my proxy server is not on the same subnet - it's an external public ip. Is there a good tutorial out there that can help me better understand this?

My router ip is 192.168.1.1 and my proxy is 69.29.x.x

I tried this:

```
PROXY_IP=69.29.x.x
PROXY_PORT=6000
LAN_IP=`nvram get lan_ipaddr`
LAN_NET=$LAN_IP/`nvram get lan_netmask`
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $LAN_NET -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $PROXY_IP:$PROXY_PORT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp -j SNAT --to $LAN_IP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -s $LAN_NET -d $PROXY_IP -p tcp --dport $PROXY_PORT -j ACCEPT
```

internet works from lan ports but is not redirected transparently to the squid proxy server. I do not fully understand the above. I got it from http://phinfinity.com/2012/09/20/setting-up-a-transparent-pass-through-proxy-with-iptables/

Comment: ServerFault is a better place for network infrastructure administration questions, I think.